# Pass ajax form value to controller codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('form.ajax-form').onclick('login_submit', function() {
                        var obj = $(this), // (*) references the current object/form each time
                            url = obj.attr('action'),
                            method = obj.attr('method'),
                            data = {};

                        obj.find('[user_email]').each(function(index, value) {
                            // console.log(value);
                            var obj = $(this),
                                email = obj.attr('user_email'),
                                value = obj.val();

                            data[email] = value;
                        });

                        obj.find('[user_pass]').each(function(index, value) {
                            // console.log(value);
                            var obj = $(this),
                                pwd = obj.attr('user_pass'),
                                value = obj.val();

                            data[pwd] = value;
                        });

                        $.ajax({
                            // see the (*)
                            url: url,
                            type: method,
                            data: data,
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                // $("#feedback").html(data);
                            }
                        });

                        // console.log('Trigger');
                        return false; //disable refresh
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php echo form_open('welcome/login', array('class' => 'ajax-form','style'=>'z-index: 202')); ?>

            <input name="user_email" type="email" class="login_email" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <br />
            <input name="user_pass" type="password" class="login_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <a href="#" class="forgot_pass">Forgot login details?</a>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" id="login_submit" style="margin-left:20px;">Sign in</button>
            </label>
                    </form>
            <?php if(isset($login_error) && $login_error !=='') { ?><div class="alert alert-danger login_err"><?php echo $login_error; ?></div> <?php } ?>
            <!--                    </div>-->
```

Hi i am trying to pass the email and password to the controller in codeigniter.

Any idea how to do that please help?

Comment: Wont a "normal" AJAX call work? The controller is the first to get the data. So just put in the URL to the controller (and it's method), then let it take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify a big deal by doing:

```
$('#ajax-form').submit(function(){
 var form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      // $("#feedback").html(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: How do i pass values into my controller with this. Would it be a normal post function?